# What are the types of data in which the order of instances does matter?

Tags: datasets

In general, the order of instances in the datasets that are used in machine learning is immaterial. But there are exceptions. Timeseries data is one such exception I know. Consider the following two excerpts

#1: From **[4.3 Representing tabular data](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf#page=107)** of the textbook titled **Deep Learning with PyTorch** by *Eli Stevens et.al.*

> At first we are going to assume there’s no meaning to the order in
> which samples appear in the table: such a table is a collection of
> independent samples, **unlike a time series, for instance, in which
> samples are related by a time dimension**.

#2: [From an answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24894/18758)

> Moreover, there are **datasets that contain elements whose order in the
> dataset can be relevant** for the predictions, such as datasets of
> **time-series data**, while, in mathematical sets and multi-sets, the
> order of the elements does not matter.

I want to know the types of such data in which the order of instances does matter. Are there any other kinds of data except Timeseries in which the order of instances does matter?